# Lubuntu alternate install stops at *starting Bluetooth

Tags: installation, usb, lubuntu

Ok i dont realy know what im doing. i have a load of eee PCs that i want to install Lubuntu on I have used the universal usb installer to run from usb. installing Lubuntu 11.10 alternate os. i plug in the usb turn on pc enter setup set os install status to start, set boot disck order to usb then reboot. select option to install Lubuntu follow all the instructions no special settings all default or as you expect. get to the end and reboot I have tried both leaving the usb in and removing it each time when the pc restarts i just get the lines *starting ntp *starting Bluetooth then nothing leftit for hours still nothing any ideas for a simleton please

Answer (score 0):

this mean that your desktop environment has gone faulty. press alt-f2 and then re-install lubuntu-desktop. or check for your /etc/x11/xorg.conf in case you're using NVIDIA driver.